# How get the time when i call NSLog in format string and further to use this time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

How get the time when i call NSLog in format string and further to use this time?
I need time to microseconds?

```
2017-09-28 20:19:39.383263+0300 NIR[5677:1383138] а
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method you can use.  It returns an (NSString *) with the current timestamp.  It's a little messy because there's not a formatter string to get the seconds including milliseconds:

```
- (NSString*)dateTimeWithMS
{
    CFAbsoluteTime timeInSeconds = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    NSDate *d = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:timeInSeconds];
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss";
    NSString *s = [df stringFromDate:d];
    int ms = (int) round(1000 * (timeInSeconds - floor(timeInSeconds)));

    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\.%000d", s, ms];

    return(result);
}
```

Basically we get the time, use the standard formatting, and then append the milliseconds.

You can test it with this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        NSLog(@"Time #%d with MS = %@", i, [self dateTimeWithMS]);
```

You will get output something like this -- you can see Xcode's timestamp matches ours:

```
2017-09-28 18:28:10.781 TimeMillisecondTest[2497:463749] Time #0 with MS = 2017-09-28 18:28:10.780
2017-09-28 18:28:10.781 TimeMillisecondTest[2497:463749] Time #1 with MS = 2017-09-28 18:28:10.781
2017-09-28 18:28:10.781 TimeMillisecondTest[2497:463749] Time #2 with MS = 2017-09-28 18:28:10.782
2017-09-28 18:28:10.781 TimeMillisecondTest[2497:463749] Time #3 with MS = 2017-09-28 18:28:10.782
2017-09-28 18:28:10.782 TimeMillisecondTest[2497:463749] Time #4 with MS = 2017-09-28 18:28:10.782
2017-09-28 18:28:10.782 TimeMillisecondTest[2497:463749] Time #5 with MS = 2017-09-28 18:28:10.782
2017-09-28 18:28:10.782 TimeMillisecondTest[2497:463749] Time #6 with MS = 2017-09-28 18:28:10.782
2017-09-28 18:28:10.782 TimeMillisecondTest[2497:463749] Time #7 with MS = 2017-09-28 18:28:10.783
2017-09-28 18:28:10.782 TimeMillisecondTest[2497:463749] Time #8 with MS = 2017-09-28 18:28:10.783
2017-09-28 18:28:10.783 TimeMillisecondTest[2497:463749] Time #9 with MS = 2017-09-28 18:28:10.783
```